python selenium dom elements are not found
I am trying to automate reading data from a website with differently named tags Like <c-practitioner-search ... >. I tried to see them as normal tags and used find_elements() but there was no success in it.
Here is part of the HTML code:
<div data-item-id="256b3a7e-2963-49b0-9841-1397b03c7f02">
  <div data-priority class="ui-widget"> 
    <c-practitioner-search data-data-rendering-service-uid="40">
      <div c-practitionersearch_practitionersearch="">
        <div c-practitionersearch_practitionersearch="">
          <lightning-layout c-practitionersearch_practitionersearch="" class="bread-crumbs-style slds-grid">
            <slot lwc-4p3ig5mhdla class="slds-slot">
              <lightning-layout-item c-practitionersearch_practitionersearch>
                <slot>
                  <a c-practitionersearch_practitionersearch class="search-result-name-text-style">  Title </a>
                  <small c-practitionersearch_practitionersearch>
                     <ul c-practitionersearch_practitionersearch class="browser-default">
                       <li c-practitionersearch_practitionersearch class="search-result-text-style"> Info 1 </li>
                       <li c-practitionersearch_practitionersearch class="search-result-text-style"> Info 2 </li>
                       <li c-practitionersearch_practitionersearch class="search-result-text-style"> Info 3 </li>
                     </ul>
                   </small>
                 </slot>
               </lightning-layout-item>
             </slot>
           </lightning-layout>
         </div>
       </div>
     </c-practitioner-search>
   </div>
 </div>
                

Tags that are like <c-practitioner-search> or <div c-practitionersearch_practitionersearch>are not returned and cannot be worked with.
So How can i get the info from the this kind of code?
in case you need the original website : https://bams.vba.vic.gov.au/bams/s/practitioner-search
Since the website is dynamic using other things like bs4 is useless.
I tried a loop over all elements of the body and i saw only like 20% of the elements, so where is other elements that i see in browser inspect?
Here is a part of my code to see all elements:
class PractitionerScraper:
    def __init__(self, url:str):
        main_path = pathlib.Path().absolute()

        driver_path = main_path / "chromedriver.exe"
        service = Service(executable_path= driver_path)

        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=service)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(4)
        self.driver.get(url)

    def search(self, time_to_load:int):
        time.sleep(time_to_load)
        main_div = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body div[class*='main']")

        all_tags = main_div.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*")
        for tag in all_tags:
            print(tag.tag_name)


It seems to have some kind of bot protection

@JeffC well it's a job , i need a way to get around it

In my case, those elements don't show up until the Search button is clicked.
Here is the code using webdriver to pull all the titles, you could expand it to get all the other details.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://bams.vba.vic.gov.au/bams/s/practitioner-search'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

elem_search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Search"]')))
elem_search.click()

all_items = []

# Getting items from the first page
elem_item = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="search-result-name-text-style"]')))
for item in elem_item:
    all_items.append(item.text)

# Iterating over the other 9 pages
for i in range(2, 11):
    elem_next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//button[text()="{i}"]')
    elem_next_page.click()
    elem_item = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="search-result-name-text-style"]')))
    for item in elem_item:
        all_items.append(item.text)

However, for such tasks, I would usually try to look into the browser API calls as it sometimes possible to extract the necessary data with a POST request. Apparently it works for the given website. Check out this code:
import requests
import json

msg = ('{"actions":[{"id":"130;a","descriptor":"aura://ApexActionController/ACTION$execute",'
       '"callingDescriptor":"UNKNOWN","params":{"namespace":"","classname":"PractitionerSearchUtil",'
       '"method":"getPractitioners","params":{"searchParamWrapper":{"practitionerName":"",'
       '"registrationCategory":"","registrationClass":"","accreditationType":"Building","pageNumber":%s}},'
       '"cacheable":false,"isContinuation":false}}]}')

context = ('{"mode":"PROD","fwuid":"ZDROWDdLOGtXcTZqSWZiU19ZaDJFdzk4bkk0bVJhZGJCWE9mUC1IZXZRbmcyNDguMTAuNS01LjAuMTA",'
           '"app":"siteforce:communityApp","loaded":{"APPLICATION@markup://siteforce:communityApp":"7766VpxH8B5ZgC8Vrgi-bQ",'
           '"COMPONENT@markup://instrumentation:o11ySecondaryLoader":"nSN3-Xh18FbrdCVGqsWZnw"},"dn":[],"globals":{},"uad":false}'),

query_url = 'https://bams.vba.vic.gov.au/bams/s/sfsites/aura?r=10&aura.ApexAction.execute=1'

output = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    data = {'message': msg % i,
            'aura.context': context,
            'aura.pageURI': '/bams/s/practitioner-search',
            'aura.token': 'null'}
    
    req = requests.post(query_url, data=data)
    
    result = json.loads(req.text)['actions'][0]['returnValue']['returnValue']['PractitionerDetailList']
    output = output + result

The output looks like this. But be aware that the search result is limited to 500 items, which means you won't be getting all of them. Filtering with the searchParamWrapper in msg could be a way to solve it.
[{'accountId': '0015m000005zlweAAA', 'accreditationType': 'Building', 'detailURL': 'https://bams.vba.vic.gov.au/bams/s/practitioner-detail?inputParams=4kJrFwhH8NkDASSlvhB1OLm0bPtCHoI89qyIP085njkBEls14yPsUa2Rz31qgadG', 'haveFilteredVICAccreditations': False, 'haveNoAMRAccreditations': False, 'haveNoVICAccreditations': False, 'haveOnlySuspendedEndedAMRAccreditations': False, 'haveUnfilteredVICAccreditations': False, 'isADR': False, 'practitionerId': '#067547', 'practitionerName': '1 HOMES PTY LTD', 'registrationCategoryWithClass': 'Domestic Builder Company - Domestic Builder - Unlimited', 'registrationClass': 'Domestic Builder - Unlimited', 'registrationId': 'a1O5m000000Y1YuEAK', 'registrationNumber': 'CDB-U 73774', 'registrationType': 'Victorian practitioner', 'status': 'Current', 'statusStyleClassName': 'Current'}]
...
...

